# Why can't gsl_vector_alloc be called before main starts?

Tags: c, static, gsl

From the 21st century C book:

> Static variables, even those inside of a function, are initialized
>   when the program starts, before main, so you can’t initialize them
>   with a nonconstant value.
>
> ```
> //this fails: can't call gsl_vector_alloc() before main() starts
> static gsl_vector *scratch = gsl_vector_alloc(20);
> ```

Why can't gsl_vector_alloc be called before main starts?

Comment: Because it yields a nonconstant value. What else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you quoted from the book is the answer, i.e. because it wouldn't be compliant to the C standard.

```
All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage 
duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.
```

Although I believe something like this is possible in C++ under certain conditions.